# Save UISwitch Status - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I know this has been asked before but I have yet to find a solution to this. I am attempting to save UISwitch state so that no matter which VC I enter, that switch state is still active. However, anytime I leave the VC the switch is in, it's resorts to off. Currently this is the code I'm using to save the switch state:

```
- (IBAction)tvpSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {
    if (sender.isOn) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"on" forKey:@"tvpSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


}
else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"off" forKey:@"tvpSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}}
```

I then put this is any VC viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"tvpSwitch"]isEqualToString:@"on"]) 
{
      (sender.isOn=YES);
}
else
{
      (sender.isOn=NO);
}}
```

It also flags in the viewWillAppear method that reads: "Use of undeclared identifier 'sender'."I usually try using the Reference Guide but I'm having a difficult time identifying where this is going wrong. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the `UISwitch`? Because where is your `sender` you should make reference to the switch (like, self.nameOfTheSwitch)

Answer (score 0):

Like you have an `IBAction` there, I suppose you created the `UISwitch` trough `Interface Builder`. If that's the case, create an `IBOutlet` from the `UISwitch` and then always reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet `sender` is the parameter passed in the `IBAction` method which is a reference to the `UISwitch`.

In the other view controllers you need some reference to that `UISwitch` but if you want only to check that state without being able to change it in the UI, just get it from `NSUserDefaults` and use it.

By the way there are designated methods of `NSUserDefaults` for saving a `BOOL` type.

```
- (IBAction)tvpSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:sender.isOn forKey:@"tvpSwitch"];
}
```

---

```
BOOL switchState;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tvpSwitch"];
   // do something with switchState
}
```

Comment: I tried your code is in some ways its working how I want it. The issue I have remaining is that it only reads it as being in an on state. The goal is so that when there is a change in state, it saves to user defaults and then I can recall that status. I tried a few if statements with your above code and haven't found a solution yet. Would you have an idea for this? If I also misunderstood your answer, I apologize.